# Defining comma-separated values in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am trying to make a restriction that requires a value of two positive integers separated by a comma. I looked through other posts but it seemed like what I'm trying to do is simpler than in other problems. This is what I have so far:

```
<xs:element name="cell" maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <xs:simpleType>
               <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
                      <xs:pattern value="[1-1000],[1-1000]"/>
               </xs:restriction>
       </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

I want the resulting value to look like this (example): `<cell>4,15</cell>`.

I have a second element `<dimensions>` that is similar, but instead of a comma, I want the integers separated by the letter 'x.' So an example of a value for this element would be `<dimensions>20x20</dimensions>`.

First, am I even using the right base data type? I also tried a whole bunch of combinations using `xs:string` with no luck. Second, how do I express the patterns?

Comment: You should also be aware that the maxOccurs is not allowed within xs:element. It should be used when declaring this element as a member of it's parent element within a complex type. For example, if `<cell>` is defined as member of `<grid>`, you set the maxOccurs of cells in the definition of grid.

Comment: You may want to brush up on regex; the character group `[1-1000]` allows any character of the group consisting of (a) the range '1' to '1' (so: '1'), and (b) any of '0', '0', or '0' -- that is, it's equivalent to `0|1`.

Comment: bitfiddler, yes, <cell> has a parent element; I just didn't include it here because it wasn't relevant to the pattern question. 

C.M. Sperberg-McQueen, yeah, I figured that out when the only valid values I was getting started with '1.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XSD will allow a pair of comma-separated, nonnegative integers within a `cell`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="cell">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="\d+,\d+"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

A similar `xs:pattern` could of course be used for `dimensions`:

```
        <xs:pattern value="\d+x\d+"/>
```